# [Odoo][Odoov13] Run method with selenium

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, odoo, xorg, odoo-13

I have python script ( using selenium ) which is running by clicking in button in Odoo.
This script run chrome with GUI by chromedriver.
When it try to run i have error:

> The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no
>   longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

Everything is installed on my virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04 on computer with Hyper-V (on windows)
I know that this error is show because script don't have access to X server.
So i add user to X with : 
xhost +SI:localuser:odoo_user

but still i have stat same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by:

1. `pip install PyVirtualDisplay`
2. Download and install (you don't need that same version):
   https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/xserver-common_1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4_all.deb.html
   `dpkg -i xserver-common_1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4_all.deb`
3. `apt install xfvb`
4. You always need to have that same version of chromedrive and chrome browser in system.

After that chromedriver can run X session without GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Yesh I faced the same issue while I use selenium in Odoo, Check your chrome version and download supported chrome driver for your chrome and move it to your "usr/bin" give full permission to the location and try this code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
     
def test(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Comment: I have same problem. I have matched version. even independent python script running fine but when implement inside Odoo framework (form view button) then it  giving me error.  ```[ERROR] SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from tab crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

the solve for this question is install Selenium Grid and PyVirtualDisplay (you can use docker for this) and try with Remote option:

webdriver.Remote(URL_SERVER_SELENIUM, options);

Its works for me.

Best Regards.